# Amcharts Pie Chart show country only on hover

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

In this demo http://www.amcharts.com/demos/simple-pie-chart/#theme-light it shows the country and percent both at first view and on hover.  I would like only the percent to be shown at first view, and show country: percent only on hover.

Is this possible?
Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use chart property [`labelText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#labelText) to specify what is being shown for slice labels.

To show only percents, you would need to set it to `"[[percents]]%"`.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "Lithuania",
    "litres": 501.9
  }, {
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "litres": 301.9
  }, {
    "country": "Ireland",
    "litres": 201.1
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "litres": 165.8
  }, {
    "country": "Australia",
    "litres": 139.9
  }, {
    "country": "Austria",
    "litres": 128.3
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "litres": 99
  }, {
    "country": "Belgium",
    "litres": 60
  }, {
    "country": "The Netherlands",
    "litres": 50
  }],
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country",
  "labelText": "[[percents]]%"
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;"></div>
```